# JBOSS doesn't take my own libs

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, war

**Check out my answer for solution**

I'm deploying a WAR in a Jboss Server, but I don't get that Jboss take my own libs, it is using its own libs (I think that is my problem).

```
Structure of my project:
- projectName
--- src
----- main
-------webapp
---------WEB-INF
-----------jboss-classloading.xml
-----------jboss-deployment-structure.xml
-----------jboss-web.xml

---target
-----wars
-------myWar.war
```

At first I only had jboss-web.xml and jboss-deployment-structure but I read that jboss-classloading is necessary for this problem.

```
jboss-web.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<jboss-web>
<context-root>/myProject</context-root>
<class-loading java2ClassLoadingCompliance="false">
    <loader-repository>projectName/src/target/wars:loader=myWar.war
        <loader-repository-config>java2ParentDelegation=false</loader-repository-config>
    </loader-repository>
</class-loading>
```

```
jboss-classloading.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classloading xmlns="urn:jboss:classloading:1.0"
parent-first="false"
domain="myWar.war"
top-level-classloader="true"
export-all="NON_EMPTY"
import-all="false">
</classloading>
```

It shows me 2 errors:

```
30/07/2015 07:30:03,795 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."myWar.war".FIRST_MODULE_USE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."myWar.war".FIRST_MODULE_USE: JBAS018733: Error al procesar la fase FIRST_MODULE_USE de deployment "myWar.war"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [jboss-as-server-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011426: No se pudo implementar el proveedor de persistencia empacado de la aplicación 'org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence'
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceProviderHandler.deploy(PersistenceProviderHandler.java:79)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.deploy(PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.java:45)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [jboss-as-server-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
        at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3404) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceProviderHandler.deploy(PersistenceProviderHandler.java:73)
        ... 7 more
```

```
30/07/2015 11:47:03,930 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service     thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."myWar.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."myWar.war".PARSE: JBAS018733: Error al procesar la fase PARSE de deployment "myWar.war"
at   org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [jboss-as-server-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at  org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018014: No se logró analizar sintácticamente el descriptor "/content/myWar.war/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml" en [4,5]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.JBossWebParsingDeploymentProcessor.deploy(JBossWebParsingDeploymentProcessor.java:79)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [jboss-as-server-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
... 5 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[4,5]
Message: Unexpected element 'class-loading' encountered
at org.jboss.metadata.parser.util.MetaDataElementParser.unexpectedElement(MetaDataElementParser.java:109)
at org.jboss.metadata.parser.jbossweb.JBossWebMetaDataParser.parse(JBossWebMetaDataParser.java:210)
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.JBossWebParsingDeploymentProcessor.deploy(JBossWebParsingDeploymentProcessor.java:71)
... 6 more
```

If you need more information let me know it.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT WITH NEW ERROR**

```
31/07/2015 12:29:52,896 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/ksjm_ksjm_01]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) JBWEB000287: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.grupobbva.sl.soa.gui.catalogos.ApplicationContextListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grupoDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.grupobbva.sl.soa.configuracion.dao.impl.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/dao-configuracion-applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
```

dao-configuracion-applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${configuracion.servicio.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${configuracion.servicio.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${usuario}" />
    <property name="password" value="${password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${configuracion.servicio.hbm2ddl}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${configuracion.servicio.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver">${configuracion.servicio.driverClassName}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${configuracion.servicio.default-schema}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan"
        value="com.grupobbva.sl.soa.core.domain, com.grupobbva.sl.soa.core.domain.config" />
</bean>
```

I have read in other post that it would work if I upgrade my sessionFactory bean to hibernate 4....but it does not work for me =(

Comment: I edited my post with a new error.

Why does it work in my laptot but it does not work in another computer? :(

Comment: Edited...updating hibernate3 to 4 does not work for me

Comment: Where in your web.xml file are you adding your <tag-lib>s?  Those are required if you're using JSTL prefixes.  Are you using JSP files for your views?  Are you using Spring MVC?  Could you provide me more info about your project?  If I understand your problem correctly, you're getting errors deploying your .war file into the JBoss server due to your libs not getting recognized.  Am I understanding you correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this issue. I deleted jboss-classloading.xml and jboss-deployment-structure.xml and it worked!! This way there is no "conflicts" between libraries :)

I hope it can be useful for someone.